# Error on property NameIDPolicy.AllowCreate when parsing legitimate SAML Request coming from Shibboleth

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am implementing a SingleSignOn solution (IdP) based on your software and having a little problem when receiving a SAMLRequest (http redirect), generated by Shibboleth.

This request contains an element: `<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="1"/>`

The SAML2 standard (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf lines 2186 an later) states that this is a boolean attribute.
The SAML standard is only talking about the possible values "true" and "false"
But the xml standard https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#boolean (on which SAML2 standard is based) specifies: booleanRep ::= 'true' | 'false' | '1' | '0'

So the element sent by Shibboleth should be correct.

But when parsing the SAML request I get a error message:
System.FormatException: String '1' was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

I examined the sources in github

In the ITfoxtec project this NamedIdPolicy is defined in https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/662544c8e08c46bf1736bd72fcf31d06aeac1d9d/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Schemas/NameIDPolicy.cs

And the parsing is done in https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/662544c8e08c46bf1736bd72fcf31d06aeac1d9d/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Util/GenericTypeConverter.cs
The error message was generated by line 121:                 return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));

I recreated the error message with this code snippet in LinqPad:

```
  bool? AllowCreate = GenericConvertValueToNullable<bool>("true");
  AllowCreate.Dump(); // returns boolean value true

  AllowCreate = GenericConvertValueToNullable<bool>("1"); // Triggers error in Convert.ChangeType call
  AllowCreate.Dump();

  T? GenericConvertValueToNullable<T>(string value) where T : struct
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
      return null;
    }
    else
    {
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
  }
```

The error occurs when converting the "1" value to boolean

I also found a possible solution

Insert these lines before the Convert.ChangeType line:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
{
  int intValue;
  if(int.TryParse(value, out intValue))
  {
    if (intValue == 0 || intValue == 1)
    {
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(intValue, typeof(bool));
    }
  }
}
```

In the result code, 'true' | 'false' | '1' | '0' can all be used as valid values

I tested that "7", "-1", "x" still cause the error message, as they are not valid accoording to xml standard, so thats also correct.

Is it possible that you make these changes, and release a new version of the NuGet package?

Maybe there are more boolean attributes that need complying to the xml standard?

Answer (score 0):

The link https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/662544c8e08c46bf1736bd72fcf31d06aeac1d9d/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Schemas/NameIDPolicy.cs is to a working Draft.

The SAML 2.0 core standard from 2005:
https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf where  NameIDPolicy.AllowCreate is described in chapter 3.4.1.1.

I don't think AllowCreate can be anything else then `true` and `false` according to the SAML 2.0 core standard.

**1) UPDATE**

It is possible to add support for not strictly SAML 2.0 Authn request and thereby accept NameIdPolicy.AllowCreate non SAML 2.0 standard values.

You can implement your own version of the [Saml2AuthnRequest](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnRequest.cs) class inherited from [Saml2Request](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2Request.cs) class.

Where you change the [NameIdPolicy](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnRequest.cs#L45) to your own NameIdPolicy implementation.

```
public MyCustomNameIdPolicy NameIdPolicy { get; set; }
```

The MyCustomNameIdPolicy is implemented based on the [NameIdPolicy](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Schemas/NameIDPolicy.cs) code, where the [AllowCreate](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Schemas/NameIDPolicy.cs#L21) property type is changed to a string.

```
public string AllowCreate { get; set; }
```

The AllowCreate will then accept both `true`, `false`, `1` and `0` as strings.

**2) UPDATE**

The reason for the problem you describe is probably because you need to implement MyCustomNameIdPolicy in `GetXContent` [line 144](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnRequest.cs#L144) and `Read` [line 169](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnRequest.cs#L169).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with github. I checked master branch is same at this point.
SAML 2.0 Chapter 1.3 refers to xs:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema for common datatypes. And AllowCreate is described as boolean, which implies  'true' | 'false' | '1' | '0' see:  https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#boolean. Unless this boolean is defined in another namespace.
And I could not find another definition for boolean in the SAML2 namespace

Anyway, the Service Provider, using Shibboleth SP solution,  is sending me <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="1"/> element. 

They think '0' '1' are allowed

Comment: Some extra information. I created a sample Authn request at https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php and I changed the generated AllowCreate value from "true" to "1".
Then I validated the changed Authn request at https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php (entity id: http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php and target url: http://idp.example.com/SSOService.php no other parameters)

Valid. True and 1 are both valid there

Comment: I do not know way samltool.com accept '0' and '1'. I still think the valid format for AllowCreate is 'false' and 'true'. I think that shibboleth.net do not follow the SAML 2.0 standard using '0' and '1'.

Comment: Well, bad luck for me. Because the service provider will keep on working with Shibboleth. So I will have to find a solution myself.
By the way, I liked the ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 software. And thanks for the quick responses to my question.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a possible solution by implementing your own Saml2AuthnRequest and NameIdPolicy.

Comment: Thanks. I will look in to your solution. Looks ok and is easy to implement. I will check if and where my code is using this attribute. That wil also have to change. But I think this will work.

Comment: I ran into another problem. I used your suggestion, but get the same error, probably because, when loading the xml request into the custom AllowCreate property typed as string. In https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Util/GenericTypeConverter.cs line 78 the xml value is first being converted to boolean. So even when my custom AllowCreate property is of type string, just before that, the value from the httpRequest (true, false, 0, 1) is cast to boolean. And that still will fail when 0 or 1 is in the request.

Comment: Please see 2) UPDATE.

Comment: I see my error. I tried to inherit from Saml2AuthnRequest, not directly from Saml2Request. But now I'm having problems with ToXmlDocument() which is an INTERNAL extension method of XmlDocument https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Extensions/XElementExtensions.cs and also a lot of the Saml2Constants.Message properties https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Schemas/Saml2Constants.cs#L114 are internal. So they cannot be used and have to be redefined in my custom code.

Comment: Okay, you then have to copy more parts of the code I'm afraid.